# SwiftUI, assign view to variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following view:

```swift
struct ChordPadView: View {
    [...]

    init() {
        [...]
    }

    var body: some View {
        [...]

        if globalState.interfaceMode == .Normal {
            HStack {
             [...]

              SomeView(playChord, stopChord) {
                  VStack {
                      Text(showType ? "\(chord.note)\(chord.type)" : chord.note)
                          .font(Font.custom("AeroMaticsBold", size: 15))

                      if (!self.hideNumeral) {
                          Text(self.numeral ?? chord.numeral ?? "")
                              .font(Font.custom("AeroMaticsBold", size: 8))
                      }
                  }
              }
            }
        } else {
            SomeOtherView(playChord, stopChord) {
                VStack {
                    Text(showType ? "\(chord.note)\(chord.type)" : chord.note)
                        .font(Font.custom("AeroMaticsBold", size: 15))

                    if (!self.hideNumeral) {
                        Text(self.numeral ?? chord.numeral ?? "")
                            .font(Font.custom("AeroMaticsBold", size: 8))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I have two very different view, `SomeOtherView` and `SomeOtherView` and within the logic of my view I need to pass to either one or the other the very same block of content.

How can I refactor my code in order to avoid the duplication and stay DRY? Is there a way to assign the `VStack` block to a variable to use it in multiple places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom view for the `VStack`. Either use it directly in the if-else statement, or pass it to  `ChordPadView`.

```
struct ChordPadView: View {
    var body: some View {
        if (true) {
            HStack {
                VStackView()
            }
        } else {
            VStackView()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Or

```
struct ChordPadView<Content: View>: View {
    var content: Content
    
    init(content: Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if (true) {
            HStack {
                VStackView()
            }
        } else {
            VStackView()
        }
    }

}


struct VStackView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("VStack View")
        }
    }
}
```

---

*The else statment is never executed since the condition is always true.*